# python subprocess won't run phantomjs, but works in linux command line

Tags: python, subprocess, phantomjs

when I run this on CENTOS 7 server, it works from bash:

```
[myserver]$ /home/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /home/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/thumbnails.js -3933029 91 q5975 "http://mysite/explore?viz=summary_slider"
Rendered 'http://mysite/explore?viz=summary_slider' at '/home/thumbnails/th-3933029c91q5975.png'
```

But if I do this in python, using subprocess, I get an error:

```
import subprocess
phantomjs_call = u'{0}phantomjs {0}thumbnails.js {1}'.format(phantomjspath, link)
rendered = subprocess.check_output(phantomjs_call.split())
```

returns

```
/home/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /home/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/thumbnails.js "http://mysite/explore?viz=summary_checkbox"
Unable to render '"http://mysite/explore?viz=summary_checkbox"'
```

is there something weird about subprocess args? or the shell environment is not right?

Next, I tweaked it and passed in the full string as one argument, then I got OSError:

```
rendered = subprocess.check_output(phantomjs_call)
# didn't split this into multiple arguments
>>>[Errno 2] no such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying many different variations on `subprocess`, this is what worked with `phantomjs`: `subprocess32`!!!

```
    import subprocess32 # not the default version; this supports timeouts
    for (_id, link) in link_list:        
        phantomjs_call = u'{0}phantomjs {0}thumbnails.js {1} {2} {3} {4}'.format(phantomjspath, _id, link)
        """note: this generates a string like
/home/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs 
/home/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/thumbnails.js 51514 
"http://mysite/explore?viz=summary_text"
        """
        try:
            process = subprocess32.Popen(phantomjs_call, shell=True, stdout=subprocess32.PIPE)
            # make sure phantomjs has time to download/process all the pages in the list
            # but if we get nothing after 180 sec, just move on
        except Exception as e:
            print(phantomjs_call)
            print('Popen failed', e)

        try:
            output, errors = process.communicate(timeout=180)
        except Exception as e:
            if debug == True: 
                print("\t\tException: %s" % e)
            process.kill()
            return "\t\tException: {0}".format(e)
        # output will be weird, decode to utf-8 to save heartache
        phantom_output = []
        for out_line in output.splitlines():
            phantom_output.append( out_line.decode('utf-8') )
```

This is python2.7 -- it's probably easier in python3, but saving it here because it took me a lot of trial and error to make subprocess32 work with phantomjs.

Also - I didn't share the `thumnails.js` file but it's javascript that parses the command line inputs into phantomjs for as many urls as you want, and constructs filenames using those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

How about that

```
import subprocess
phantomjs_call = '{0}phantomjs {0}thumbnails.js {1}'.format(phantomjspath, link)
print(subprocess.check_output(phantomjs_call), shell=True)
```

or

```
import os
phantomjs_call = '{0}phantomjs {0}thumbnails.js {1}'.format(phantomjspath, link)
print(os.system(phantomjs_call))
```

Comment: I tried shell=True and it put me into a shell when debugging. Might it lead to the system hanging? 

I'll try the os.system() method next.